# To sum output of OUTER Join on condition from two tables of a database , across all the databases

Tags: mysql, database

I am using a query of `OUTER JOIN` on a column to take output from two tables of a databases.

Since I have multiple dbs , how can I take the sum of this `OUTER JOIN` output from all dBs , in a single query?

This is the query I use on the two tables(`calls_located_info`,`calls_info`) of a dB where the primary key is `CALLID` :

```
select calls_info.SERVING_RSRP,calls_located_info.TERMINATING_LATITUDE,
 from calls_info left outer join calls_located_info on
((calls_located_info.CALLID = calls_info.CALLID)) where TERMINATING_LATITUDE IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Your query contain a sintax  error (wrong comma after the last column and before form clause)
Left join is euivalent to left outer join  and  you don't need ((  ))
 around on condtion  (and  do the fact you have only a condition you don't () for nothings )

```
  select 
        calls_info.SERVING_RSRP
      , calls_located_info.TERMINATING_LATITUDE
  from calls_info 
  left join calls_located_info  on calls_located_info.CALLID = calls_info.CALLID  
  where TERMINATING_LATITUDE IS NOT NULL;
```

if you need the same select from several db you can use union  all  and perform the sum on the result

```
   select sum(col1) from (
      select 
            a.SERVING_RSRP  as col1
          , b.TERMINATING_LATITUDE 
      from db1.calls_info  as a 
      left join bdb1.calls_located_info as b on b.CALLID = a.CALLID  
      where b.TERMINATING_LATITUDE IS NOT NULL

      union all 


      select 
            a.SERVING_RSRP
          , b.TERMINATING_LATITUDE
      from db2.calls_info  as a 
      left join bdb2.calls_located_info as b on b.CALLID = a.CALLID  
      where b.TERMINATING_LATITUDE IS NOT NULL

      ......

      union all 


      select 
            a.SERVING_RSRP
          , b.TERMINATING_LATITUDE
      from dbN.calls_info  as a 
      left join bdbN.calls_located_info as b on b.CALLID = a.CALLID  
      where b.TERMINATING_LATITUDE IS NOT NULL 
  ) t
```